# Android amazon s3 upload part size

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm sending files to amazon s3 server like this and really need to change part sizes of sending file from default amazon (5mb) to 1 mb, is there any way to do that?

```
 TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                            "mydir/test_dir",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                            data.getData().getLastPathSegment(),    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                            root        /* The file where the data to upload exists */
                    );;
```

Comment: Maybe this helps http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html

Comment: @RubioRic wow, great. Do you think there is an option to add this at client side or only at server-side?

Comment: I'm no expert in amazon s3, sorry. But linked info is related to configuration at client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum part size for S3 multipart uploads is 5MB. (See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPart.html). The Transfer Utility uses the smallest allowable part size, which is usually 5MB.